# External signing PDF with iTextsharp (3)

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

Need to sign PDF by using an external webservice that signs the document hash, the process has to be done in 2 steps, and using a temporary empty signature.

Following [Priyanka question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042503/sign-pdf-hash-using-java-and-itext) and [Grazina question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559547/external-signing-pdf-with-itext) and reading the mkl answers on that posts, I currently have invalid signature, even after adding the hash prefix like Grazina did.

iTextSharp version: 5.5.13.1

This program is another aproach to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669163/external-signing-pdf-with-itext-2).
Current code (compiles and starts calling **SignPDF** method):

```
public class PDFSigner
{
    private const string SIG_FIELD_NAME = "sigField1";

    private void SignPDF(string pdfFilePath, string userId)
    {
        var preparedSigPdfFilePath = $"{pdfFilePath}.tempsig.pdf";
        var signedPdfFilePath = $"{pdfFilePath}.signed.pdf";

        //Get certificates chain from webservice
        var certificatesChain = this.GetUserCertificates(userId);

        byte[] hash = this.CreatePDFEmtySignature(pdfFilePath, preparedSigPdfFilePath, certificatesChain);

        //Get signature from webservice
        byte[] signedHash = this.GetSignature(hash, userId);

        CreateFinalSignature(preparedSigPdfFilePath, signedPdfFilePath, hash, signedHash, certificatesChain);
    }

    private byte[] CreatePDFEmtySignature(string pdfFilePath, string preparedSigPdfFilePath, List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> certificatesChain)
    {
        byte[] hash = null;

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
        {
            using (FileStream baos = File.OpenWrite(preparedSigPdfFilePath))
            {
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, baos, '\0', null, true);
                PdfSignatureAppearance sap = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
                sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 720, 160, 780), 1, SIG_FIELD_NAME);

                //TODO: check how to select the correct certificate, have 3 items on list, selected leaf after debug (first one)
                sap.Certificate = certificatesChain.First();

                var externalEmptySigContainer = new MyExternalEmptySignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED, preparedSigPdfFilePath);

                MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(sap, (IExternalSignatureContainer)externalEmptySigContainer, 8192);

                hash = externalEmptySigContainer.PdfHash;
            }
        }
        return hash;
    }

    private void CreateFinalSignature(string preparedSigPdfFilePath, string signedPdfFilePath, 
        byte[] hash, byte[] signedHash, List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> certificatesChain)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(preparedSigPdfFilePath))
        {
            using (FileStream baos = File.OpenWrite(signedPdfFilePath))
            {
                IExternalSignatureContainer externalSigContainer = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedPdfFilePath, hash, signedHash, certificatesChain);
                MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, SIG_FIELD_NAME, baos, externalSigContainer);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyExternalEmptySignatureContainer : ExternalBlankSignatureContainer
    {
        public string PdfTempFilePath { get; set; }
        public byte[] PdfHash { get; private set; }

        public MyExternalEmptySignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter, string pdfTempFilePath) : base(filter, subFilter)
        {
            this.PdfTempFilePath = pdfTempFilePath;
        }

        override public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            byte[] sigContainer = base.Sign(data);

            //Get the hash
            IDigest messageDigest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest("SHA-256");
            byte[] messageHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, messageDigest);

            #region Log
            var messageHashFilePath = $"{this.PdfTempFilePath}.messageHash-b64.txt";
            File.WriteAllText(messageHashFilePath, Convert.ToBase64String(messageHash));
            #endregion Log

            //Add hash prefix
            byte[] sha256Prefix = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20 };
            byte[] digestInfo = new byte[sha256Prefix.Length + messageHash.Length];
            sha256Prefix.CopyTo(digestInfo, 0);
            messageHash.CopyTo(digestInfo, sha256Prefix.Length);

            #region Log
            var messageHashWithPrefixFilePath = $"{this.PdfTempFilePath}.messageHash-with-prefix-b64.txt";
            File.WriteAllText(messageHashWithPrefixFilePath, Convert.ToBase64String(digestInfo));
            #endregion Log

            this.PdfHash = digestInfo;

            return sigContainer;
        }
    }

    public class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
        public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
        public byte[] SignedHash { get; set; }
        public List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> CertificatesList { get; set; }

        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(string signedPdfFilePath, byte[] hash, byte[] signedHash, List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> certificatesList)
        {
            this.Hash = hash;
            this.SignedHash = signedHash;
            this.CertificatesList = certificatesList;
        }

        public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.CertificatesList, "SHA256", false);
            sgn.SetExternalDigest(this.SignedHash, null, "RSA");
            return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(this.Hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);         
        }

        public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)  {   }
    }

    public byte[] GetSignature(byte[] hash, string userId)
    {
        // Request signature for hash value messageHash and return signature bytes               
        byte[] signature = null;

        //CALL WEBSERVICE:
        //signature = WEBSERVICE_CALL_TO_GET_SIGNED_HASH(hash, userId);

        return signature;
    }

    private List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> GetUserCertificates(string userId)
    {
        List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> certChain = null;

        //CALL WEBSERVICE:
        //certChain = WEBSERVICE_CALL_TO_GET_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES(userId);

        return certChain;
    }
}
```

**RESULTS OBTAINED**

[image: Check image from Acrobat reader signature validity check]

MESSAGE HASH (BASE 64):

```
lA2cMByHLkuNdd+aHJRDy3GD2VIeIpVtzlgQGsq3cJw=
```

MESSAGE HASH WITH PREFIX (BASE 64):

```
MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIJQNnDAchy5LjXXfmhyUQ8txg9lSHiKVbc5YEBrKt3Cc
```

SIGNED HASH (base 64):

```
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
```

**UPDATE**
Tested the PDF signature with the [mkl test area](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/signature/analyze/AnalyzeSignatures.java), obtaining the following results:

```
Certificates:
Subject: [REMOVED]
Issuer: [REMOVED]
Serial: 7590871326079402939
Subject: [REMOVED]
Issuer: [REMOVED]
Serial: 1738456118788016053
Subject: [REMOVED]
Issuer: [REMOVED]
Serial: 8957244856106358046

Attribute Certificates: none

CRLs: none

SignerInfo: [REMOVED] 8957244856106358046
Certificate: [REMOVED]
Signed attribute 1.2.840.113549.1.9.4 (PKCS 9 - Message Digest)

Digest: 
3031300D060960864801650304020105000420940D9C301C872E4B8D75DF9A1
C9443CB7183D9521E22956DCE58101ACAB7709C

Signed attribute 1.2.840.113549.1.9.3 (PKCS 9 - Content Type)

Signed Attributes Hash: 
08767823328F202C1C3E5DB543785ED591C6D84D23DAF3DCBB83684B987008CB
Signed Attributes Hash Hash: 
1E2D10B23CD772D16987126182E51BD4D827DB58C497BA4129BB533A576E3548
!!! Decrypted RSA signature is not PKCS1 padded: Decryption error
Decrypted signature bytes: [REMOVED]
!!! Decrypted RSA signature does not end with the PSS 0xbc byte either

!!! Signature does not validate with certificate
```

Going to try to add the padding to the signature, help appreciated.

Comment: Currently the signing provider returns certificates with invalid key usage for signing documents, and they are fixing this, althought the document should appear as not modified since signing right? Or will have that problem until they fix that?

Comment: Updated the question with result from mkl signature analyzer program.

Comment: I just also analyzed the signature container. First off, as the quote you added indicates, the signature bytes you retrieve from your server upon decryption with the claimed signer certificate's public RSA key does neither result in something PKCS1 padded (more exactly PKCS1 v1.5 padded) nor in something PSS padded. Thus, that signature value is not what you expect, it's not a signature created for the claimed signer certificate, it's not even clear whether it's a signature at all.

Comment: Other than that your code here has a number of errors while the code in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59669163/1729265) looked in principal correct.

Comment: Thus, I propose you should first try to understand how to correctly retrieve a matching pair of signing certificate and signature from your service and then couple that with the code in the previous question.

Comment: Thank you, did what you suggested, contacted the signer webservice owner and detailed the probkem, with focus on question 1 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

## Signature value does not match signer certificate

First and foremost, judging by the result PDF **the `GetUserCertificates` call does not appear to return the signer certificate of the signature returned later by `GetSignature`** in spite of using the same `userId` value.

This is indicated by the `AnalyzeSignatures` output pasted into the question:

```
SignerInfo: [REMOVED] 8957244856106358046
Certificate: [REMOVED]
```

The SID in the single `SignerInfo` in the signature container matches a single certificate from the included set of certificates.

```
!!! Decrypted RSA signature is not PKCS1 padded: Decryption error
Decrypted signature bytes: [REMOVED]
!!! Decrypted RSA signature does not end with the PSS 0xbc byte either
```

The public key of that certificate is an RSA key and the length of the `SignerInfo` signature value matches the key length but decrypting the value using that key returns neither something PKCS#1 v1.5 padded nor a PSS structure. Thus, the "signature value" either is not an RSA signature value at all or it is a signature generated using a private key not matching the public key in the alleged signer certificate.

Thus, the first thing to do is analyzing the

```
    //CALL WEBSERVICE:
    //signature = WEBSERVICE_CALL_TO_GET_SIGNED_HASH(hash, userId);
```

and

```
    //CALL WEBSERVICE:
    //certChain = WEBSERVICE_CALL_TO_GET_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES(userId);
```

hidden parts of the code and fixing them (or the web service if the problem is located there) and only then continuing integrating this fixed code in a PDF signing frame.

## Errors of the PDF signing code frame

The PDF signing frame here contains some errors. The code in the previous question ["External signing PDF with iText (2) [closed]"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59669163/1729265) looked more correct, so I would propose basing the next approach onto the code there after finding out the correct use of the signing web service here.

Nonetheless, here an explanation of two errors that quickly caught my eyes:

```c#
byte[] hash = this.CreatePDFEmtySignature(pdfFilePath, preparedSigPdfFilePath, certificatesChain);

//Get signature from webservice
byte[] signedHash = this.GetSignature(hash, userId);

CreateFinalSignature(preparedSigPdfFilePath, signedPdfFilePath, hash, signedHash, certificatesChain);
```

#### Wrong hash sent for signing to the web service

The hash returned by `CreatePDFEmtySignature` is result of the attempt of the class `MyExternalEmptySignatureContainer` to determine the hash of the signed byte ranges.

But usually in the context of CMS signature containers (except for the most primitive kind) the actual signature bytes are not created for the document bytes directly but instead for a structure of attributes (the so called "signed attributes" or "authenticated attributes"); the hash of the document bytes is merely the value of one of those attributes.

Thus, the signature value `signedHash` for `hash` returned by `GetSignature` in `CreateFinalSignature` via `MyExternalSignatureContainer.Sign` is injected into a PKCS#7 / CMS signature container SignerInfo whose authenticated attributes have a completely different hash.

When using the iText `PdfPKCS7` class to generate a signature container, the signature value bytes have to be calculated for the hash of the result of `PdfPKCS7.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` with the parameters corresponding to those of the later `PdfPKCS7.GetEncodedPKCS7` call.

Thus, the validation of the actual signature bytes for PDFs signed like this must fail.

#### Hash wrapped in DigestInfo used where it should be naked

The hash returned by `CreatePDFEmtySignature` is wrapped in a `DigestInfo` structure (by prepending some bytes accordingly in `MyExternalEmptySignatureContainer.Sign`).

Via `CreateFinalSignature` in `MyExternalSignatureContainer.Sign` it later is given to `PdfPKCS7` as hash of the signed bytes. But here it is expected naked, not wrapped in a `DigestInfo` structure.

Thus, the validation of the hash of the signed document bytes for PDFs signed like this must fail.

Comment: Thank you, did what you suggested, contacted the signer webservice owner and detailed the probkem, with focus on previous question implementation.

Comment: While waiting for webservice signer response tried to change the code as you proposed, but to use the PdfPKCS7.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes with the same arguments as PdfPKCS7.GetEncodedPKCS7, first I need to have a hash, the same used on both methods. Used sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(messageHash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS) and but has the same problem. Waiting for the signer webservice response.