# Java itextpdf 5.5.13.3 invalid signature when external signing

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I am using **itextpdf 5.5.13.3** Java for external signing. First I create signature appearance, calculate the hash for signed attributes and leave empty place for the signature. Later when I get the signed hash from client, I insert it the PDF via MakeSignature.signDeferred.

But PDF reader is showing the signature as invalid. Complaining the PDF has been modified.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSNVt.jpg)

Mr [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl)  can you help me?

This is the code:

```
public class AndreaTest {
    
    static byte[] hash;
    
    static byte[] toSign;
    
    static Certificate[] chain;
    
    String fieldName = "sign";  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                
        String ocspUrl = props.getProperty("auditdata.ocspUrl");
        String ocspUser = props.getProperty("auditdata.ocspUser");
        String ocspPass = props.getProperty("auditdata.ocspPass");
            
        File initialFile = new File("src/main/resources/certificate.pem");
            
        InputStream pKstream  = new FileInputStream(initialFile);

        TSAClientBouncyCastle tsClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(ocspUrl, ocspUser, ocspPass, 4096, "SHA256");
        
        String originalPdf = "src/main/resources/originalPdf.PDF";
        String tempPdf = "src/main/resources/tempPdf.PDF";
                      
        setChain(pKstream);
        
        emptySignature(originalPdf, tempPdf, fieldName);
        
        String signature = "";  // signed hash signature we get from client
        byte[] signedHash = Hex.decodeHex(signature.toCharArray());
        
        createSignature(tempPdf, outPdf, fieldName, hash, signedHash, tsClient);
    }
    
    public static void setChain(InputStream userCertificate) throws CertificateException {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        chain = new Certificate[]{cf.generateCertificate(userCertificate)};
    }
    
    public static void emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');

        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, fieldname);
        
        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new EmptyContainer();
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

        os.close();
        reader.close();
    }
    
    public static void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, byte[] hash, byte[] signature, TSAClientBouncyCastle tsClient) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = getPkcs();
        sgn.setExternalDigest(signature, null, "RSA");

        byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, tsClient, getOscp(), null,
        MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(encodedSig);
        MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, fieldname, os, external);

        reader.close();
        os.close();
    }
    
    static class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
        protected byte[] sign;
        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sign) {
        this.sign = sign;
        }
        public byte[] sign(InputStream is) {
        return sign;
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        }
    }
    
    static class EmptyContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
        public EmptyContainer() {
        }
        public byte[] sign(InputStream is) {
            try {
                ExternalDigest digest = getDigest();

                Certificate[] certs = {null};

                hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(is, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));

                String temp = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(is);//.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                PdfPKCS7 sgn = getPkcs(certs);

                toSign = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, getOscp(), null,
                MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);

                return new byte[0];
            } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary) {
            pdfDictionary.put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS);
            pdfDictionary.put(PdfName.SUBFILTER, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        }
    }
    
    private static ExternalDigest getDigest() {
        return new ExternalDigest() {
            public MessageDigest getMessageDigest(String hashAlgorithm)
                    throws GeneralSecurityException {
                return DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm, null);
            }
        };
    }
    
    public static PdfPKCS7 getPkcs() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {
        return new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, getDigest(), false);
    }
    
    public static PdfPKCS7 getPkcs(@Nullable  Certificate[] certChain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        return new PdfPKCS7(null, certChain, "SHA256", null, getDigest(), false);
    }
    
    public static byte[] getOscp() {
        byte[] ocsp = null;
        OcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(new OCSPVerifier(null, null));

        if (chain.length >= 2) {
            ocsp = ocspClient.getEncoded((X509Certificate)chain[0], (X509Certificate)chain[1], null);
        }

        return ocsp;
    }   
}
```

P.S. This code that I wrote is ispired by correct version posted here [Java iText 5 invalid signature when external signing via MakeSignature.signDeferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539405/java-itext-5-invalid-signature-when-external-signing-via-makesignature-signdefer/77679920#77679920)

I don't understand where the issue

Comment: Can you share an example PDF signed by your code for analysis?